# integrating Cloud application with Onpremise

Tags: cloud, integration, hybrid, iaas

I have a product hosted in AWS which has well defined REST based API, I need to integrate this with multiple on premise applications like ERP, CRM, HR etc.
So this is kind of a Hybrid integration what are the best possible solutions ? I am looking for Open source solutions. Can I deploy an Open source ESB like Mule or WSO2 in cloud and integrate with my On premise applications?

Answer (score 2):

The cloud version of MuleESB is called CloudHub (https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/cloudhub/) which can be used for your case. However, it is not free, there is a 30-day trial available to try it out.

Essentially, the endpoints in the CloudHub flows will connect the AWS REST API with the on-premise applications.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can deploy MuleESB in the cloud, but much to my knowledge it's not multi-tenant (please correct me someone if it's not true anymore) if that's what you'd also need.
If you're ready to write connectors to these on-premise applications as well as to you product yourself, you can also try the elastic.io - it's a cloud-based integration platform with Java and Node.js SDKs for writing own API components. Serves basically the same purpose as ESB.

Answer (score 0):

Off my experience I can tell stratoacale's Symphony is a multi tenant product that may suit your needs. The latest version of it has made the SDDC solution even more simple to use, as you can have your private cloud as a base, use it as on-premise whenever, plus you can have your AWS infrastructure set as an on-premise as well. You can try their demo and see if that could work for you.